# Skies or sky in contemporary poetry

Tags: grammatical-number

Dear Learned Grammarians,

I am reveiwing a poem of mine in which I describe a plane ***death spiralling from the skies***. While I realise that in every day language and conversation I would most likely refer to 'sky' instead of 'skies', and that in poetry 'skies' has historically been permissable, is this still the case today? Or am I being quaintly old-fashioned?

Many thanks in advance for your shared wisdoms.

Cheers
Sam

Comment: I did see those posts. My query relates to what is mainstream practice in poetry today. I don't believe that has been covered.

Comment: The usage of "skies" seems fairly even throughout the ages, according to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skies%2C+sky&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cskies%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csky%3B%2Cc0). Despite its declining usage as of late, the word's not at all archaic and I can still see it having its place in contemporary literature.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, thoughts, and the useful reference to Ngram, which highlights I see an interesting divergence between the use of 'sky' and 'skies'!

Comment: If it's your poem you can do anything you like with it. It all depends on what you want to mean. If you don't *know* what you want to mean, you ought to settle that issue first.

Answer (score 1):

I can say ***skies*** when I mean, simply, the *plural* of sky:

> the December night skies this year have been marvellously clear;
>
> the skies over London, Bristol and Cardiff were cloudy every day this week.

When something falls from ***the skies*** (or *the heavens*) it seems, to me, that the sense is not plural.  And the effect, for me, is to introduce  a meaning, at least in part, metaphorical rather than literal.

Both usages sound contemporary.  Unsurprisingly the 'literal' usage is more [common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+skies%2Cthe+sky&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20skies%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20sky%3B%2Cc0).